# How to do nothing with if else in a apply lambda function?

Tags: python

I have the following code that applies a value to the column 'ASSET CLASS' if the column 'Product Type' contains a specific value :

```
df["ASSET CLASS"] = df["Product Type"].apply(lambda x: "EQUITY" if ("OPTION EQUITY" in x or "DECU EQUITY" in x
                                                                    or "ACCU EQUITY" in x or "SWAP EQUITY" in x
                                                                    or "BASKET" in x) else None)

df["ASSET CLASS"] = df["Product Type"].apply(lambda x: "FOREX" if ("OPTION FOREX" in x
                                                                  or "DECU FOREX" in x
                                                                  or "ACCU FOREX" in x
                                                                  or "FX TARGET" in x) else None)

df["ASSET CLASS"] = df["Product Type"].apply(lambda x: "COMMO" if ("OPTION COMMO" in x or "DECU COMMO" in x
                                                                   or "ACCU COMMO" in x) else None)
```

It works for every column, but the problem is that because of "`else None`", it returns None in the column asset class for the other product. I would like `else DO NOTHING` so it does not do anything to the column asset class and the next line can applies its conditions. What I actually get is :

[image]

thank you for your help.

Comment: you don't want to use `apply` here. you want to use e.g. `numpy.select`

Answer (score 0):

`apply` will convert your value based on your return value.
so if you want to do nothing, you need to have filter first and not to do the assignment.